# Haskell - Reduce list - MapReduce

Tags: haskell, mapreduce

I'm trying to reduce a list of tuples, where the values of a duplicate key are added together like this:

`[(the, 1), (the, 1)] => [(the, 2)]`

I tried this:

```
reduce :: [(String, Integer)] -> [(String, Integer)]
reduce [] = []
reduce [(k, v) : xs] = (+) [(k, v)] : reduce xs
```

I'm getting this error:

```
 Couldn't match expected type `(String, Integer)'
             with actual type `[(String, Integer)] -> [(String, Integer)]'
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**

This is the full program

```
toTuple :: [String] -> [(String, Integer)]
toTuple [] = []
toTuple (k:xs) = (k, 1) : toTuple xs

reduce :: [(String, Integer)] -> [(String, Integer)]
reduce [] = []
reduce [(k, v) : xs] = (+) [(k, v)] : reduce xs     

main_ = do list <- getWords "test.txt"
       print $ reduce $ toTuple list

-- Loads words from a text file into a list.
getWords :: FilePath -> IO [String]
getWords path = do contents <- readFile path
               return ([Prelude.map toLower x | x <- words contents])
```

Comment: What is `(+) [(k, v)]` supposed to be doing?

Comment: Also, your main problem is that `[(k, v) : xs]` matches a list containing a single element, namely `(k, v) : xs`, you should match `((k, v) : xs)` instead.

Comment: @bheklilr It's supposed to add the v's together of a k's that are the same. I'm trying to copy this `map_ list = M.toList $ M.fromListWith (+) [(x, 1) | x <- list]`

Comment: @AdegokeA: That implementation works, but you're really going to _need_ a `Map` somewhere.  Why are you trying to change that implementation?

Comment: Because I have to separate the mapping and the reducing for concurrency. I'm trying to implement the MapReduce.

Comment: What _exactly_ do you expect to be passed into `reduce`?  The pairs for one key?  The pairs for all keys?

Comment: A list of tuples where all the values are 1.

Comment: And are you trying to merge the values of duplicate keys?  Are the duplicates guaranteed to be consecutive?  Where are you checking to see if two keys match?

Comment: Yes, merge the values (better yet, add them). No they may not be consecutive. I'm not checking for that, I'm trying to follow the code snippet in my comment above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65309/discussion-between-adegoke-a-and-louis-wasserman).

Answer (score 2):

You are doing the pattern matching wrong. The pattern match should be like this:

```
  ((k,v):xs)
```

`(k,v)` represents the head of the list and `xs` represents the tail of the list. Similarly this is problematic:

```
(+) [(k, v)] : reduce xs
```

The type of `+` is this:

```
λ> :t (+)
(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```

You cannot simply do `(+) [(k, v)] : reduce xs` which doesn't appear anywhere reasonable. You have to check the contents of the String and then add second part of the tuple.

Comment: @AdegokeA What do you expect if you pass list of tuples ?

Comment: I expect to get a list of tuples but no duplicate keys, instead I want the key with an updated value. Just like the example I gave in my question.

Comment: @AdegokeA For each element in the list, you need to traverse the rest of the list and check if the first part of the tuple are equal. Based on the check you have to create a new list out of that.

Answer (score 1):

Let me point out that your function `reduce` is extremely similar to function `fromListWith` from `Data.Map`:

```hs
> :m Data.Map

> let reduce = toList . fromListWith (+)

> :t reduce
reduce :: (Ord k, Num a) => [(k, a)] -> [(k, a)]

> reduce [('a', 3), ('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('a', 10), ('b', 2), ('c', 1)]
[('a',14),('b',4),('c',1)]

> reduce [(c,1) | c <- "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"]
[(' ',8),('a',1),('b',1),('c',1),('d',1),('e',3),('f',1),('g',1),('h',2),('i',1),('j',1),('k',1),('l',1),('m',1),('n',1),('o',4),('p',1),('q',1),('r',2),('s',1),('t',2),('u',2),('v',1),('w',1),('x',1),('y',1),('z',1)]
```